# Writing back Global Variables

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, cpu-architecture

If the system has two level memory hierarchy, do you have to write back the global variable to the main memory at the end of the program if it resides in the cache-like memory for its life-span in the prgram?

Comment: No. Please read basic material about [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) & [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space); and your question is off-topic here.

Comment: Even if the architecture would require so, neither C nor C++ puts this burden on you. In other words, it is the responsibility of the C or C++ compiler. (In the future, please refrain from C/C++ questions as you typically get two distinct answers)

Comment: I am aware of the cache/virtual address mechanism. My question is more about correctness if I am to design a system with a software-managed cache and decided to allocate a global object in this cache, does C/C++ assume that this object will be written back or not at the end of the program.

Answer (score 2):

On "normal" machines, no, caches are transparent. They will just speed up memory access without visibly changing the way you access memory, all the cache eviction/sync/writeback stuff is handled in autonomy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that the cache is supposed to be transparent. My question is if there is a way that the cache-like memory knows that the liveness of an object that resides in it ends at some point, is it correct from the program perspective not to write it back or there are cases where this does not apply?